# Problema pra exclusão de dados de uma planilha

Tags: c#, asp.net, microsoft-excel

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código que faz conexão com o excel, onde o mesmo ira excluir os dados de uma aba de uma planilha.

```
 private void AtualizarPerformanceEntrega()
    {
        try
        {


           string sFileXLSX = Server.MapPath("ExportPerformanceEntrega");
           string strConnXLSX = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + sFileXLSX + "';Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";

            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(strConnXLSX))
            {
                //SQL para fazer o INSERT

                string strSQL = "DELETE FROM [Base Entregue$]";
                //Criando o OleDbCommand com o SQL e a conexão
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, connection);
                //Abrindo a conexão
                connection.Open();
                //Executando o INSERT
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                //Fechando a conexão
                connection.Close();
            }



        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Porém me retorna o seguinte erro:

> "The Microsoft Office Access database engine could not find the object
>   'Base Entregue1$'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its
>   name and the path name correctly."

Parametro do `web.config`

```
<add key ="ExportPerformanceEntrega" value="‪C:\Entrega\Performance.xlsx"/>
```

Nome da aba que eu quero fazer a exclusão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs.¹ Essa planilha vem bloqueada e sempre quando abre tem que **habilitar edição**

Obs.² Talvez seja o nome da aba, por estar separado?

Comment: Que estranho, na sua query você passa "[Base Entregue1$]", mas o nome da planilha que você destacou está sem este "1". Está correto? não tenho o excel instalado pra testar aqui.

Comment: @L.Albano  então mesmo corrigindo o código pra deixar o nome igual, ainda retorna o mesmo erro

Comment: O endereço não deveria estar com 2 barras? value="‪C:\\Entrega\\Performance.xlsx"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente o problema seja com a zona do arquivo, como ele está "bloqueado" alguns recursos podem ser barrados pelos componentes do Windows

> Obs.¹ Essa planilha vem bloqueada e sempre quando abre tem que
>   habilitar edição

O Excel, bem como o pacote Office, bloqueia a edição de documentos, planilhas e apresentações sempre que o arquivo **vem da Rede** para seu computador

Você pode desbloquear o arquivo manualmente nas Propriedades do documento e marcar a opção **Desbloquear**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É possível desabilitar essa identificação de zona de Internet no arquivo pelo editor de política do Windows

Executar -> **gpedit.msc**

Vá em Configurações do Usuário, Modelos administrativos, Componentes do Windows, Gerenciador de Anexos e habilite o item:

**Não preservar informações de zona em anexos de arquivo**

Obs: Somente para informação, esta é uma configuração de Segurança do Windows, desabilite apenas para testar se este é realmente seu problema; sugiro mantê-la habilitada

Fontes:

O que faz com que um arquivo seja bloqueado? https://www.howtogeek.com/70012/what-causes-the-file-downloaded-from-the-internet-warning-and-how-can-i-easily-remove-it/

Arquivos bloqueados: https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/understanding-the-internet-file-blocking-and-unblocking